# Scheme recursion with a conditional

Tags: recursion, scheme

I am trying to get my feet wet with some recursion using scheme, however, not matter what I try, I always end up getting an error when it starts evaluating the first branch of the if statement. The error is something similar to: "Cannot call 0. 0 is not a function". This zero is really the x in the conditional but I cannot figure out why this is happening. After some time debugging, I came to the conclusion that it's really just a recursion issue that I am not fully understanding.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

```
(define nums (list 1 5 6 7 8 9))

(define (find-len my-list x) (   
      (if (null? my-list) 
       x
      (find-len (cdr my-list) (+ 1 x) ) ) ) )

(define (len my-list) (find-len my-list 0) )

(len nums)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you have an incorrect pair of `()` surrounding the `if` expression. Try this:

```
(define (find-len my-list x)
  (if (null? my-list) 
      x
      (find-len (cdr my-list) (+ 1 x))))
```

Remember that in Scheme, a pair of `()` means "apply this procedure". For example: `(f)` applies the zero-argument procedure called `f` - so you have to be careful where you put your parentheses, they're *not* like `{}` brackets in other programming languages ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting used to the shift of functional programming

Comment: Maybe expand to show some idiomatic ways to write a list length procedure? +1

Comment: More idiomatic than using the built-in length procedure? ;)